# In vertx, Is there a way I can just change header and redirect to another server

Tags: vert.x, vertx-httpclient

I am new to Vertx, I am writing a proxy server, which will take request, update header, and send to another server. On receiving response, send the complete response as it is to client.

In vertx, Is there a way I do this straign forward or I need to implement handler for each http method and content type, to create new request and send using new client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `vertx-web` of version 3.x and below, then you can do:

```
void redirect( RoutingContext rc, String url ) {
  if( !rc.response().ended() ) 
    rc.response().setStatusCode( 303 ).putHeader( 'Location', url ).end()
}
```

Comment: in vert.x 4 there's a similar method on the `RoutingContext` so you can just do: `ctx.redirect(destination)`

Comment: @injecteer I tried, 
`rc.response().setStatusCode( 303 ).putHeader( 'Location', url ).end()`
I tried with status code 307, 308 also since http method is post.
I am also setting jwt token in header `.putHeader( "Authorization","Bearer "+token)`.
But on target server, (non vertx) its throwing 401, with message "Authentication header value is not valid". 
How can set correct header with jwt token ?

Comment: you can add your token as GET param: `putHeader( 'Location', url + '/' + token )`

Comment: I don't think a client can delegate headers to the other server, only the url, so you can use standard redirect functionality or re-issue the request from client using ajax or alike

Comment: Thanks, since I am using vertx 3.9, I used the suggested solution and Redirect works.